# Reverse in SQL by pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, reverse

I'm very new to SQL and I'd like to do something like this :

Going from

```
12 34 56 78
```

to

```
78 56 34 12
```

I tried the `reverse` function, but the result is `87 65 43 21`.

Is there a way to do this ? Thank you for reading !

Comment: [Why I should tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: you can ORDER BY desc your results; what is the 12 34 56 78? a series of fields, a string, ...?

Comment: Thanks for answering , it is a string and DESC is giving me the same results as REVERSE function

Comment: what is your DBMS? sqlserver? the string is already as it is in the db?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server. Each 2 digits is in a different column. Like 12 in column 1, 34 in column 2... Sorry my english isn't that good and I'm new to SQL so my explanations must be terrible

Comment: then please post the query that is producing the string

Comment: String is an ID provided by a third party, I just have them in my database but I need to reverse them like in my original post

Comment: Again: post the query you are using.

Comment: Why do this in SQL? I'd use a programming language for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the string_split will be useful here. Here's what it can do For your particular case (numbers are always increasing).

```
select *
  from STRING_SPLIT('12 34 56 78', ' ')
 order by value desc;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9bce1b632ecbae775fe83311c2822bd)

UPD. Here's what you can do when numbers are not always increasing

```
with splitted as(
select value, row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
  from string_split('12 34 78 56', ' '))

select string_agg(value, ' ') within group(order by rn desc)
  from splitted
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bdfeb29e73b7409550dafabf7053c62a)

Comment: it will not return a string...

Comment: Thank you for answering. I should have specified that numbers aren't always increasing that's my bad.

Comment: @colducrane check the updated answer please

Comment: I have no idea how you did it but it works just fine !! Thank you so much

Comment: @colducrane If this worked for you, please accept this as the Answer

Comment: While this is a clever idea, SQL Server doesn't guarantee that you get the values numbered in the original order thus. (This is why they have the enable_ordinal parameter in Azure.) So, `string_split` is no reliable solution here. You could use a recursive query for this or simply do this string manipulation in a programming language.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string split` to split your string into rows, then `string_agg` to get a string back with the order you want:

```
select string_agg(value, ' ') within group(order by cast(value as int) desc)
  from string_split('12 34 56 78', ' ')
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50a9ba57c3ed470438c02bf6a910c57e)

However if you don't want you numbers in increasing order, you shouldn't use `string_split` with `row_number` as suggested in the other answer because the order is NOT guaranteed. Use another function instead of `string_split`, such as `DelimitedSplit8K` from [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

Your select becomes:

```
select string_agg(Item, ' ') within group(order by ItemNumber desc)
  from DelimitedSplit8K('12 34 56 78', ' ');
```

The code of `DelimitedSplit8K`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine, but I should have taken a better example because in my example numbers are always increasing which won't always be the case